# Could not change view size by ViewPropertyAnimator?

Tags: android, animation, zooming, android-imagebutton

I want to implement zoom feature on an ImageButton by Property Animation. For example, when I click the button, it will zoom out. And when I click it again, it will zoom in.

Here is part of my code:

```
    OnClickListener clickPlayButtonHandler = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageButton clickedButton = (ImageButton) v;

            if((Boolean) v.getTag()) {
                // zoom out
                clickedButton.animate().setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator()).setDuration(500).scaleXBy(-0.4f).scaleYBy(-0.4f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        clickedButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_pause);
                        System.out.println(clickedButton.getWidth()); // output the width of the button for checking
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        clickedButton.setTag(false);
                        int d = clickedButton.getWidth();
                        System.out.println(clickedButton.getWidth());// output the width of the button for checking

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) { }
                });

            } else {
              // process zoom in 
            }
        }
    };
```

I printed the width of the button before the animation start and the animation finished. However, I found they were the same. I thought when the zoom out animation finished the button width should be small than before. But it didn't.

Could not change view size by ViewPropertyAnimator?

Comment: You are scaling in float values while you check difference in integer values?

Comment: Have you tried `setScale` and see if it works?

Comment: @StoneBird in onAnimationEnd I used clickedButton.setScaleX(-0.4f); before System.out.println(clickedButton.getWidth()); but the result is the same as before.

Comment: Try explicitly call `start()` at the end and see if it works. Probably not a solution but should help debugging.

Answer (score 2):

There won't be changes in `clickedButton.getWidth()`, because the width of a view is not affected by scaling. You can think of getWidth() as a way to get *unscaled* width of a view. To change the width of a View requires a new measure/layout pass.

`ViewPropertyAnimator` doesn't change View's width/height or anything that could potentially trigger another layout pass. This is simply because layout passes are expensive and therefore could cause frame skipping, which is the last thing we want see during an Animation.

If you need to get scaled width of the button, you can do `getScaleX() * clickedButton.getWidth()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ObjectAnimator`:

```
    ObjectAnimator xAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(clickedButton, "scaleX", 1.0f, -0.4f);
    ObjectAnimator yAnimator = 
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(clickedButton, "scaleY", 1.0f, -0.4f);
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.setDuration(500);
    animatorSet.playTogether(xAnimator, yAnimator);
    animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator());
    animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    clickedButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_pause);
                    System.out.println(clickedButton.getWidth());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    clickedButton.setTag(false);
                    int d = clickedButton.getWidth();
                    System.out.println(clickedButton.getWidth());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
    });
    animatorSet.start();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The width is still the same. I think maybe only the  size of background resouce was changed instead of the size of view.